# How to make jquery ui dialog enable after appending it to form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using a jqueryui dialog in my project.The problem is that when dialog result is saved the form becomes freezed. If i don 't append jquery dialog to form the texbox values in dialog are not available in btnAddDetails_Click event.By appending dialog to form it becomes disable. My code is

```
var dlg = $("#dialog1").dialog({

                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                height: 400,
                width: 570,
                position: "center",
                resizable: false
            });


            $("#ibtnAddDetails").click(function () {
                $("#dialog1").dialog("open");
            });

            $("#ibtnSave").click(function () {
                dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
                $("#dialog1").dialog("close");
                              });
            $("#ibtnClose").click(function () {
                               $("#dialog1").dialog("close");
            });
```

Aspx code is

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

  <p>
            <strong style="margin-left: 66px">Account Number: </strong>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAccountNumber" Style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 24px;
                height: 30px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="button" value="Add Details" name="Submit" id="ibtnAddDetails" />
        </p>
<div id="dialog1" title="Add Details">
                        <p>
                            <strong style="margin-left: 36px">Account Title: </strong>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAccountTitle" Style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 55px;
                                height: 25px; width: 300px; border-radius: 0px;" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:TextBox>

                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <strong style="margin-left: 36px">Account Type: </strong>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAccountType" Style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 50px;
                                height: 25px; width: 300px; border-radius: 0px;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                        </p>
           <input type="button" value="Save" cssclass="button" id="ibtnSave" />
         <input type="button" value="Cancel" cssclass="button" id="ibtnClose" />
                </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

How to open dialog again in enable form after closing it by save input button so that user edits details in it.

Comment: I don't see the form element in your code examples. Can you add that your code example?

Comment: form element is in master page this is an inherited page

Comment: I'd need to see an example w/ the form to help you. Also, you use "dlg.parent()", but your HTML example doesn't show the parent element of the dialog. That will affect the answer.

Comment: i have added complete code

Answer (score 1):

Well I can tell you these lines will give you a lot of trouble:

```
$("#ibtnSave").click(function () {
   dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
   $("#dialog1").dialog("close");
});
```

If you inspect the source of the dialog element after initializing it, you'll notice the parent of #dialog1 is different. jQuery UI does special wrapping for styling etc... therefore, dlg.parent() definitely not doing what you want.

Also, you should never need (or should you want to!) move an initialized dialog element around on the DOM after it has already been initialized. I'm guessing this is what's leading to the "form freezing" you mentioned.

If you truly need to move the dialog element (although I'm skeptical), you should destroy it and reinitialize it after moving it. For example:

```
dlg.destroy().appendTo("#somethingelse").dialog({...});
```